# Prove there exists dense open set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $G$ be an open set in $X$ and $D$ be a dense open set in $G$.Show there exists a dense open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $V\cap G=D$.

Since $D$ is open in $G$, there exists $V$ open in $X$ such that $D=G\cap V$ and as $D$ is dense in $G$ thus it intersects every open set of $G$, which will of the form $G \cap U$.
Thus $D\cap G\cap U\neq \phi \implies \left( G\cap V\right)\cap \left(G\cap U\right)\neq \phi\implies V\cap \left(G\cap U\right)\neq \phi$. Since $G\cap U$ is arbitrary open set in $X$ thus $V$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: @Mathemagician this is obvious by the way it is written.

Comment: Not to me,Pedro. Never hurts to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is clearly incorrect: $G\cap U$ is not an arbitrary open set in $X$, since $G$ need not even intersect every non-empty open set in $X$. There is nothing to keep your $V$ from being just $D$ itself. For a specific counterexample let $X=\Bbb R$ and $G=D=(0,1)$.

HINT: Let $V=D\cup(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}G)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $D$ being dense only tells you that for every open $U$ such that $G \cap U$ is nonempty you have $G \cap U \cap D \neq \emptyset$, hence choosing $V$ the way you did you can only guarantee $V \cap U \neq \emptyset$ for those $U$ such that $G \cap U$ is nonempty. What you need to do is to enlargen the $V$ you chose to also intersect these open subsets disjoint of $G$, for example by taking $$V' := V \cup \bigcup_{U \subseteq X \text{ open, } U \cap G = \emptyset}U.$$
Then we still have $V' \cap G = V \cap G = D$, but have dealt with all the other open subsets of $X$ disjoint of $G$.

To understand what goes wrong in your proof, look at some example like $X = \mathbb{R}$, $G = (0,1)$ and $D = (0,1)$. Following the idea of your proof we could take $V = (0,1)$ but this is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$.